# Node JS -Routing Behavior with Cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

A simple scenario I was trying and wondering how this is actually working.

My Routes:

```
    <div class="form">
        <h1>Welcome ,<%= USERNAME %> back to the site!</h1>
        <a href="/Story/1">Story 1</a>
        <a href="/Story/2">Story 2</a>
        <a href="/Story/3">Story 3</a>
        <a href="/Story/Blog">Blog 3</a>
        <p><a href="/logout">Logout</a></p>
    </div>
```

Route handler is generic I would like to build and not a bit specific:

//Parameter Handling:

// So the intention is just to get the wildcard part from the URL and set the cookie parameter "myString" accordingly in this middlewire.

```
app.param("id", (req, res, next, id) => {
  console.log(id);
  if ((id === "1") | (id === "2") | (id === "3")) {
    res.cookie("myString", "Story");
  } else {
    res.cookie("myString", "Blog");
  }
  next();
});

// Generic Route Handler
app.get("/Story/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(` <h1>${req.cookies.myString}=> ${req.params.id}</h1>`);
});
```

But the outcome is:
When I click any story link, I am receiving below response:

> http://localhost:3000/Story/1
> Outcome is: Story=> 1

And I see my cookie also set "myString" as 'Story' as expected.

> http://localhost:3000/Story/Blog
> Outcome is: Story=> Blog

I have verified, now my cookie has set to "Blog" as expected)

But the above outcome is showing **Story => Blog!** I was expecting this to be **Blog => Blog**.

*Interestingly if I just refresh the page then I am getting the expected result.*

Seems the cookie is NOT set properly while the below piece of code was executed!
`` res.send(` <h1>${req.cookies.myString}=> ${req.params.id}</h1>`); ``

Can someone help me to understand this behavior / Asynchronous nature?

- Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was a basic one and I missed it, unfortunately!
The app parameter handler is setting up the cookie on the response part.

```
app.param("id", (req, res, next, id) => {
  console.log(id);
  if ((id === "1") | (id === "2") | (id === "3")) {
    res.cookie("myString", "Story");
  } else {
    res.cookie("myString", "Blog");
  }
  next();
});
```

As I am calling next() so it is calling the app. get() function with the same request obviously and by that time the request part was unchanged and so it returns always old information.

As a solution, I used the global variable `app.locals.myString` and it started working as I was expecting.

Hence closing this question.

- Thanks.